# RAML: representing a URL parameter that has a fixed enumeration of values

Tags: api, raml

In my RAML 1.0 spec, I would like to represent a `uriParameter` whose value is one of a set list of enumerated tokens. For example, `_format` can only be one of: `csv`, `json` or `ttl`.

As far as I can tell from reading the RAML spec, that's not possible at the moment unless I include JSON schema declarations. Can RAML encode enums without JSON schema, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, by using [RAML 1 data types](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#raml-data-types):

"Data types can describe a base or resource URI parameter, a query parameter, a request or response header, or a request or response body. Data types are built-in or custom. A built-in type can be used anywhere the API expects data. Custom types can be defined by extending the built-in types as well as named and used like built-in type"

Example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: bla
types:
  foo:
    type: string
    enum: [ json, csv, ttl ]
/bar/{_format}:
  uriParameters:
    _format:
      type: foo
  get:
```